# Validity of free particle in an energy eigenstate approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In many occasions we assume a particle to be free and in an energy eigenstate. For example, when we deal with a Fermi gas we assume that the nucleon is a free particle in an energy eigenstate and we calculate all sorts of stuff. We do something very similar when studying beta decay, where we assume that at time zero the soon-to-decay nucleon is moving freely inside the nucleus in an energy eigenstate. We then work with the weak force as a perturbation to the free particle Hamiltonian. My question is: why do we always assume that particles are in an energy eigenstate? Couldn't the nucleon in the example of a Fermi gas be in a position eigenstate instead? Or maybe in a superposition of many different energies all with equal weight? If I started calculations with those different assumptions would I obtain different results?